# JQuery and Azure Table, Is there a way to insert an entity with JQuery?, What happens with the account key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, azure

I need to insert an entity in a Azure Table directly from Javascript in a browser, using the REST Api for Tables, I would like to use jQuery, but i can't found any code to do that, and I don't know, for example, what happens with the account key. Should I expose my account key in the page? I am very sure that is a very very bad idea, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until June 2012, there was no way to do this without sharing your keys which, as you state, is likely to be a very bad idea.

With the June 2012 capabilities, you can consider using a Shared Access Signature to provide varying levels of access to the table, or part of the table.

How you'd use it is very much dependent upon your scenario but I'd expect that you'd want to do this only for authenticated users, passing the Shared Access Signature over an SSL connection with a short expiry time, possibly with a partition key per user if you have a limited number of users.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395415.aspx

Comment: Thanks Andy, I am going to check this, it can be a good approach, but really i can't figure out yet how to doing.